# Как словить использование скроллбара?

Tags: javascript

Как словить использование скроллбара? 
P.s. Неообходимо словить событие не прокрутки страницы а именно использование скроллбара браузера.

Comment: `onClick` не всплывает до корня документа, значит прокрутка скорее всего элемент браузера. Можно ловить `onScroll` и отсеивать те события, что сделаны нажатием пробела, колесиком мыши или стрелочками. )

Comment: А как это сделать ? d.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
        if(e.target.onmousewheel) alert();
    });

Comment: Увы нет. Причем в любом случае сначала вызывается `onScroll`, а потом уже что-либо другое, странно это, и хром и мозила так делают. Можете на вызов 'onScroll' вешать таймер, который в течении 20ms будет смотреть происходили ли в это время еще какие-либо события (при клике на прокрутку они не будут происходить). Если не будет лучше идей - я напишу это решение как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться плохим, но действенным способом. Убрать через overflow-y стандартный скроллбар и встроить на страницу любой js плагин имитирующий scrollbar, например jscrollpane.
Так же нашлось в архивах вот такое: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972542/how-to-detect-mouseup-on-a-scrollbar-or-scrollend-event

Comment: Это не подходит, небходимо ловить событие именно стандартного скролла. Идея Rolandius мне понравилась, но не знаю как её можно реализовать.